# Simple way of converting Selenium browser scripts to Jmeter scripts?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, jmeter, load-testing

I am looking for a way to convert Selenium Browser automation scripts that already currently work, into Jmeter scripts. Baring in mind I have no load testing expereince only Browser UI automation. I know there is a tool called Blazemeter and taurus, but am looking for a simple solution that is free?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 1):

Just record them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Find `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` in the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and click "Start"
2. [Configure your Selenium tests to run through JMeter proxy.](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) The code below is for Firefox

   ```
   org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
   proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8888");
   DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
   ```
3. Run your test. JMeter will capture the requests and save them under [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)